# Downsides to using include\** in visual studio projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

With most visual studio projects I've worked on I eventually run into merge conflicts because the visual studio csproj file includes a large number of lines for including files, and eventually two commits added a line to the same spot in the csproj file.

```
<Content Include="Views\View1.cshtml" />
<Content Include="Views\Shared\View2.cshtml" />
<!-- snip a hundred more views -->
```

We also use web deployment packages, and at some point always run into someone adding a .css file to the file system, but forgetting to include it as part of the visual studio project. Which results in it not being in the deployment package and never getting deployed to the test site.

I recently found out it is possible to do wildcard includes that will include all files and sub directories, like this.

```
<Content Include="Views\**" />
<Content Include="Styles\**" />
```

Is there any downside to this? It seems like it will solve both the merge problems and the forgetting to include a file in a project problems.

Comment: Perhaps mentioning at least `**.cshtml`, otherwise, what if you - by accident - include your private `ssh` key to your project and later embed it in a program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The potential downside is including potentially sensitive files in that subdirectory that shouldn't be included, or including other files that a developer randomly puts in her `Views` or `Styles` folder for testing purposes, but never expected to actually have it included in the project.  Of course, the same could go for other temporary code files that a developer may have in the physical folder location but not actually wanting to include it in the project.

To avoid this, you should consider the following syntax:

```
<Content Include="Views\**\*.cshtml" />
<Content Include="Shared\**\*.cshtml" />
<Content Include="Shared\**\*.css" />
```

This will include all files in any subdirectory.  If you actually only want to include those files in that directory, try

```
<Content Include="Views\*.cshtml" />
<Content Include="Shared\*.cshtml" />
<Content Include="Shared\*.css" />
```

etc., grabing only the file types that really should be in the file (and only in that subdirectory).  You could also use an `Exclude` attribute if you know that you don't want to include a particular file in that subdirectory.

For more information see:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171453.aspx#BKMK_Wildcards

A couple other suggestions come to mind as well:

1. Some of this problem could be avoided by using naming conventions your whole dev team follows, and ensuring that developers are assigned clear tasks that they work on together.
2. Some of this probably could be alleviated by dividing your projects up when the number of files in the project becomes too cumbersome to deal with.  Are all of those models and shared files really used by all of the controllers in that application?  Would it be better to split out some controllers into separate projects, and take the associated models/views/shared resources with them?  Would it be better to have shared resources in their own library separate from this particular project?

Comment: The one giant PITA of using globs in your csproj, is when you use Visual Studio to add/include a new file, VS goes in and totally rewrites the entire thing to go line by line again.

Comment: Even with only 10 views in a project if two people add a view and commit, it seems like visual studio always wants to add the new view in the same location in the csproj, so the second person to commit gets a conflict (which is easy to resolve but annoying). I've always wondered why visual studio didn't just keep the files ordered alphabetically.

Comment: I found that VS rewrites to line by line when I delete a file, but adding a new file was fine.